# How do I get the root directory of a process programmatically?

Tags: linux, process, system-calls

On Linux, every process has its own root directory. For most processes, this is `/`. However, `chroot` can change that. This information is exposed via `/proc`. However, how do I find out the root directory of a process programmatically? Is there a syscall, or, libc function for it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether there is another way, but lots of programs rely on the machine readable files in `/proc` to get additional information about processes and there's nothing inherently wrong with that.

Here's an example of a process finding its own root dir programmatically via `/proc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  char foo[PATH_MAX+1];
  int count = readlink("/proc/self/root", foo, PATH_MAX);
  if(count < 0) {
    perror("Can't find root dir (is /proc mounted here?)");
  } else {
    foo[count]=0;
    printf("My root dir is %s\n", foo);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there isn't. There exists a command to do this which is pwdx, here is its code https://elixir.bootlin.com/busybox/latest/source/procps/pwdx.c. It also reads root dir from /proc. You can get the pid of your process using getpid function.

Comment: I highly doubt the linked code does what euphoria83 is asking for, as it just reads `/proc/$$/cwd`, which is the wrong symlink, and the question is about finding out the current chroot without reading from `/proc`.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to just use a for loop. This is a one-liner that will print out the root directory of each of the processes you wish (proc1, proc2, proc3):

> for i in $(ps -ef | grep -E 'proc1|proc2|proc3' | awk '{ print $2 }'); do ls -ld /proc/$i/root; done